# How to write on a virtual webcam in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv, video-streaming

I want to capture a video from a real webcam, apply filters with **openCv** and write the filtered video on a virtual webcam, to stream it on web.

I don't have problem with the first 2 points, but I don't know how I can write on a virtual webcam.

It's possible?

How can I do it?

I use **openCv** with **C++** on **Debian**.
Thanks

Comment: or if you have another idea to stream the filtered video...

Comment: How does one "write to" a webcam? What does it mean?

Comment: how do you plan on doing the streaming? Instead of making a virtual webcam, just host the streaming service directly from your app. Should be easier. Making a virtual cam involves driver programming which is much more complex than simply hosting a service. Maybe find an open source streaming server and modifi it a little bit with your new features.

Comment: @sanJacinto: I think that on Linux, a webcam write a file in /dev/something. I want write that file instead of a real webcam

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, actually this is possible. A quick and dirty way to do this is to use [WebcamStudio](https://sourceforge.net/p/webcamstudio/wiki/Home/).
That will create a new video device (e.g., /device/video2) that other programs see as a normal video device and can take its input from desktop, so you just set it up to capture a part of the screen that OpenCV's output is shown there.

A better but more technical way is to use the [V4L2 loop back module](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback). This way you can simply pipe the output of OpenCV to the module which is seen as a regular video device by the other programs. See the readme at the bottom of this page:
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback
and the wiki page:
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki
for more information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. the solution with v4l2 loopback seems very interesting.
can you suggest me handbooks or "howto" for it? I looked for them, but they are difficult to find...

Comment: I edited the answer, see if that's enough to understand how to use it. If you need an OpenCV example, right now I'm busy later tonight or tomorrow I can write an example on ubuntu.

Comment: How do I actually do it though?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a combination of `v4l2loopback`, `OBS Studio` and `obs-v4l2sink`.

Use `OBS Studio` to capture video from your device, then `obs-v4l2sink` is a small plugin that writes output into `/dev/video*` of your choice.

[image: v4l2sink]

https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki/OBS-Studio

https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink