# OpenCV(programmed in C++) stdout piped to ffmpeg(in bashscript)?

Tags: c++, bash, opencv, ffmpeg, pipe

I am using the following bash script to pipe the output of OpenCV which is an out.avi file converting that file to a stdout using the tail command and piping the output to ffmpeg

```
./OpenCV & \
tail -n +0 -f out.avi  | ffmpeg -i pipe:0  -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename '%03d.ts' stream.m3u8
```

This works but causes latency issues.

I have tried to change the C++ code so that the frame gets written to a stdout using `cout << frame;` here is some of the code.

```
imshow( window_name, frame );//show frame
video.write(frame);//rec to avi
cout << frame;
```

From the above code I get the window to display the processed image, the frame is saved in avi format and from the last line i get printed to the command line the pixel values of the frames.

Now I have tried the following Bash script to pipe this stdout to ffmpeg with no success.

```
./OpenCV | ffmpeg -i pipe:0  -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename '%03d.ts' stream.m3u8
```

I also tried

`./OpenCV | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s 480x320  -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_segment_filename '%03d.ts' stream.m3u8`

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that `cout<< frame;` is printing pixel values of the `Mat` structure defined by openCV. What do you need is the actual binary data of the frame which you can retrieve using `imencode` 
for example

```
std::vector<uchar> buff;    
cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buff);
for (auto i = buff.begin(); i != buff.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i ;
```

if you want to test it, you can write the buffer to a file and see the output like this

```
std::vector<uchar> buff;
cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buff);
std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("example.jpg", std::ios::binary);
for (auto i = buff.begin(); i != buff.end(); ++i)
{
    //std::cout << *i;
    myfile << *i;
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Thesane. Got the code working only change made was to remove the auto and declare it as `vector<uchar> :: iterator i;`  so for loop was `for ( i = buff.begin(); i != buff.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i ;`  `auto` would not work for me.