# How do I emulate a webcam in python

Tags: python, webcam, opencv

I created a program in python that centers your face in the frame. It only does this in an openCV window. Is there a way to use that output as a webcam? (For video calls) This is the code:

What is the best way to emulate a webcam in Windows 10?

Is there a library that can help. This is the code that centers your face:

```
import cv2
import os
cascPath = os.path.dirname(
    cv2.__file__) + "/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    frameHeight = frame.shape[0]
    frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,
                                         scaleFactor=1.1,
                                         minNeighbors=5,
                                         minSize=(60, 60),
                                         flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    distanceX = frameWidth / 2
    distanceY = frameHeight / 2
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0,255,0), 2)
        distanceX = x + (w / 2)
        distanceY = y + (h / 2)
        # Display the resulting frame

    frontX = 0
    frontY = 0

    if (distanceX > frameWidth / 2):
        frontX = frameWidth - (2 * (frameWidth - distanceX))
        distanceX = int(frameWidth / 2)

    if (distanceY > frameHeight / 2):
        frontY = frameHeight - (2 * (frameHeight - distanceY))
        distanceY = int(frameHeight / 2)

    frameCut = frame[int(frontY): int(distanceY * 2), int(frontX): int(distanceX * 2)].copy()

    #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    #blur = cv2.medianBlur(frame, 51)
    
    allBlack = frame
    allBlack[0:frameHeight, 0:frameWidth] = [0, 0, 0].copy()

    #frameResized = cv2.resize(frameCut, (frameHeight, frameWidth))

    cutHeight = int((distanceY * 2) - frontY)
    cutWidth = int((distanceX * 2) - frontX)

    x1 = int((frameWidth - cutWidth) / 2)
    x2 = int(((frameWidth - cutWidth) / 2) + cutWidth)
    y1 = int((frameHeight - cutHeight) / 2)
    y2 = int(((frameHeight - cutHeight) / 2) + cutHeight)

    allBlack[y1:y2, x1:x2] = frameCut
    #blur[y1:y2, x1:x2] = frameCut

    #cv2.imshow('cut', frameCut)
    #cv2.imshow('resized', frameResized)
    cv2.imshow('Output', allBlack)
    #cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
    # press ESC to quit
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you checked a similar (now closed) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480034/how-to-simulate-a-webcam-device for a potential answer to your question?

Comment: you can use a software like fakewebcan, and save the setram of you output as mp4 and transmit it with fakewebcan